# Change the directory name in groovy

Tags: groovy

I need to change a folder name in groovy. I try to rename the folder name, but no luck.

```
    class Example {
    static void main(String[] args) {
       String a = "Hello";
           def fine = "C://Users//senthiln-1//generated-project";
       def d=new File(fine);
       print d;
       def newDir = "C://Users//senthiln-1//generated-project-new";
       if (d.exists()){
           print "ssss"
       }
      def s= d.renameTo(newDir);
       print s;
      // println(a.plus("\"));
       //println(a.plus("World Again"));
     
    }
 }
```

Comment: directory or even one file in it could be blocked by some process.